# How to detect Unicode version in PHP and PCRE?

Tags: php, unicode, pcre

Unicode 7.0.0 was released in June 2014. It will take a while for a PCRE release to include this and another while for PHP to include the updated PCRE library. The current Unicode version in PCRE/PHP is 6.3.0 as of July 2014. Is there a way to detect which Unicode version is being used from a PHP script? `phpinfo()` is silent on the matter.

Does the Unicode version make any difference to anything except PCRE? I can't see how it would affect other libraries such as mb_string because (as far as I know) they don't care whether a code point is assigned or not, or what properties it has (block, script, letter, mark, etc.).

Comment: Is there any particular difference that you're interested in? Perhaps you can feature-detect it. Eg. test PCRE's behaviour on a particular code point or similar.

Comment: @NisseEngström True, you could detect code points that have been added (assuming every version has added code points from the previous version). The down-side is that you have to maintain your own library of Unicode versions. Also, there would be no way of checking for future versions unless you check every code point against the known assigned ones in the latest release. Even then all you'd know is that it's some future version, not how significant the changes are.

Comment: I have an interest in Sinhala. If I write code to check whether a given string is Sinhala and only using assigned code points it will work differently once PHP is updated with the next PCRE version>8.35. I currently have no way of detecting this except to check for specific characters and manually add the code points in `[\P{Cn}\x{0DE6}-\x{0DEF}]`. If they assign more code points to the Sinhala block in the future the code becomes even more complicated. It would be much easier to say `"Results based on Unicode $cur_ver. Latest Unicode is $new_ver"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been in contact with the maintainer of PCRE and he informs me that it has no function to return the Unicode version it was compiled with. Therefore, PHP can't tell either. He will add this functionality into some future version of PCRE but can't promise when.

Answer (score 2):

`PCRE_VERSION` can be help if you ignore custom build option (`--with-pcre-regex=DIR`) and patch.

```
> php -r 'echo PCRE_VERSION, PHP_EOL;'
> 8.34 2013-12-15
```

The following table shows the correspondence among PHP and PCRE and Unicode versions.

```
PHP                     | PCRE | Unicode
-----------------------------------------
5.5.10                  |8.34  | 6.3.0
5.5.0 / 5.4.14 / 5.3.24 |8.32  | 6.2.0
5.4.9 / 5.3.19  8.31    |8.31  | 6.1.0
5.3.0                   |7.9   | 5.1.0

Unicode | PCRE
-------------------
7.0.0   | 8.36
6.3.0   | 8.34, 8.35
6.2.0   | 8.32
6.1.0   | 8.31
6.0.0   | 8.13, 8.20, 8.21, 8.30
5.2.0   | 8.02, 8.10, 8.11, 8.12
5.1.0   | 7.9, 8.0
5.0.0   | 7.0
```

**source**

- http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcre/pcre-8.35.php
- http://www.pcre.org/news.txt